# Transforming Robinson to Equirectangular

Tags: coordinate-system, gdalwarp

I need convert this http://bioval.jrc.ec.europa.eu/products/gam/images/large/access-map.png (is it robinson?) to Equirectangular (ESPG:32662) How can i get this using gdalwarp?

Answer (score 1):

Since the png file has no georeferencing information, you have to georeference the file manually.

This is rather simple if you have QGIS, and use Natural Earth shapefiles as reference, or the Openstreetmap background from the Openlayers plugin.

Gdalwarp needs GCP ( Ground control points), and you get those with QGIS by just clicking on the image and on the reference background.

Comment: Can it be directly georeferenced into EPSG 32662, or does Mike need to georeference to Robinson (or whatever projection it is) and then transform?

Comment: You get better results if you use the projection it looks like. This is the Robinson projection: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Robinson_projection_SW.jpg and it looks rather similar.

Comment: .... will edit soon

Comment: Hello Andrey! Thank you for the response. Could you please give us more details? I’m not experienced in GIS and maps :( How exactly should I make a georeference? I downloaded a map from here http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-raster-data/10m-natural-earth-1/ but do not know what to do with it. Could you please describe an order of actions in details and where to click?

I would also like to know what to enter into GDLAWARP. As far as I understand, EPSG is when there is no Robinson projection. How exactly will the command look like? 

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: See this basic tutorial on georeferencing: http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/map_georeferencing.html